# Why C# Struct behave different as property? (compare to declared as field)

Tags: c#, struct

I understand struct is value type. But I do not understand why it behave like this?
Is it because i didn't treat it as immutable? or is it has something to do with the auto property?

```
using System;

namespace StructQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static StructType structAsProperty { get; set; }
        static StructType structAsField;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            structAsProperty.InjectValue("structAsProperty");
            structAsField.InjectValue("structAsField");

            //debugger says structAsProperty.GetValue() is null
            Console.WriteLine(structAsProperty.GetValue());
            Console.WriteLine(structAsField.GetValue());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public struct StructType
    {
        private string value;
        public void InjectValue(string _value)
        {
            value = _value;
        }
        public string GetValue()
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It obviosuly because of property(not auto but at all)  .... [with struct you always get a copy not references](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yQAKTN)

Comment: There isn't a single attribute in this code.  Are you trying to use terminology from some other language that uses the same words as C# but gives them totally different meanings?

Comment: @BenVoigt property， i meant property sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at what happens in this statement:

```
structAsProperty.InjectValue("structAsProperty");
```

We don't have to go far. The very first thing that must happen is to resolve the `structAsProperty` part of the statement. The key here is understanding the compiler re-writes property `get` and `set` sections as a *method calls* behind the scenes.

So what we really have here is a call to a method that returns our struct value. I say "value" here rather than "object" because structs are *value types*. With value types, passing to or returning from a method results in *a copy* of the value.

Now we know enough to understand what happened. We are calling `InjectValue()` on a copy of the property struct, not the instance in the property itself. Next we modify this copy via it's `InjectValue()` method... and then promptly forget the copy ever existed.

You can fix it like this:

```
var prop = structAsProperty; //now we have a variable to keep the result of the implicit get accessor method
prop.InjectValue("structAsProperty");
structAsProperty = prop;
```